# how to insert a search form in custom content

Tags: 7, search

I'm trying to insert a search form in the middle of some custom HTML on a Panel Page.  There's already the Search Block on the page somewhere else.  The Search Widget is available, but it gets inserted *after* the custom HTML, which is not what I want.  I thought I could do something like
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search-block-form.tpl.php/7

```
<div class="container-inline">
<?php if (empty($variables['form']['#block']->subject)): ?>
<h2 class="element-invisible"><?php print t('Search form'); ?></h2>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php print $search_form; ?>
</div>
```

or

```
<?php
drupal_get_form('search_form');
?>
```

but the PHP doesn't seem to execute (naturally, I have PHP selected as the input.).

**Edit:**
This produced a search form in the correct place, but the CSS conflicts with the existing Search Block.

```
<?php print render(drupal_get_form('search_block_form')); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was close but needed to declare the variable.  I still don't really understand what's happening here, but it works.

```
<?php global $search_form; print render(drupal_get_form('search_form')); ?>
```